# Transposing Excel data from standard row/columns into 1 column per unique row, and as many rows as there were columns

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, transpose

I have some random data in Excel in this format:

```
ID number/Col_B/Col_C/Col_D/Col_E

001/'test'/'test'/'test'/'test'

002/'test'/'test'/'test'/'test'

003/'test'/'test'/'test'/'test'
```

I would like to transpose it (pivot table?) so that there is 1 column per ID number, and 1 row per every other column... so like this:

```
-ID Number----001 / 002 / 003

'Col_A'    'Test'  'Test' 'Test'

'Col_B'    'Test'  'Test'  'Test'

'Col_C'    'Test'   'Test'  'Test'
```

Is this possible? I tried creating a pivot table by highlighting my full dataset and dragged the ID column so that there is 1 column per ID.. but then if I add the other cols (A B C) as rows, it doesn't look like what I need.. and if I add them into the middle (values) box, it counts/sums/mins/maxes them but I just want the value itself..

Answer (score 1):

Highlight cells, copy. Choose destination, right click, Paste Special and choose transpose

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA

```
Sub Redesigner()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim hc As Integer, hr As Integer
    Dim ns As Worksheet

    hr = 1 ' count rows on top
    hc = 1 ' count column on left

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    i = 1
    Set inpdata = Selection
    Set ns = Worksheets.Add

    For r = (hr + 1) To inpdata.Rows.Count
        For c = (hc + 1) To inpdata.Columns.Count
            For j = 1 To hc
                ns.Cells(i, j) = inpdata.Cells(r, j)
            Next j

            For k = 1 To hr
                ns.Cells(i, j + k - 1) = inpdata.Cells(k, c)
            Next k

            ns.Cells(i, j + k - 1) = inpdata.Cells(r, c)
            i = i + 1
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Using Transpose Formula and extend to needed rows and columns

```
={Transpose(A1:A20)}  ' CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER  Array FORmula !!!
```

Using default transpose function

```
Select Table -> Copy -> Select cell where to transpose -> Right click Mouse -> Select Transpose
```